# Querying all objects including soft deleted ones of a SoftDeletableModel

Tags: django, python-2.7, soft-delete, django-model-utils

I'm try to get rid of home-brew solution to favor more standard ones. My previous pattern:

```
class MarkDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        if "instance" in self._hints:
            return super(MarkDeleteManager, self).get_queryset()
        return super(MarkDeleteManager, self).get_queryset().filter(deleted=False)

    def all_with_deleted(self):
        return super(MarkDeleteManager, self).get_queryset()

    def deleted_set(self):
        return super(MarkDeleteManager, self).get_queryset().filter(deleted=True)

    def using(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' if a specific record was requested, return it even if it's deleted '''
        return self.all_with_deleted().using(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'd like to replace this with django-model-util's `SoftDeletableModel` but I don't see any `all_with_deleted` like functionality in the `SoftDeletableManagerMixin` -  it only overrides `get_queryset` and that's it. My architecture is decentralized, and when I notify other nodes about soft deletions I need to access those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll solve this that way:

```
from model_utils.models import SoftDeletableModel

class MyModel(SoftDeletableModel):
    all_objects = models.Manager()  # To access soft deleted objects as well

    name = models.CharField()
    ...
```

This way I can access all the objects by saying `MyModel.all_objects.all()` instead of my old pattern's `MyModel.objects.all_with_deleted().all()`. `MyModel.objects.all()` will provide only the non soft deleted ones in both cases.

Comment: In latest django-model-utils the `all_objects` manager [already comes from upstream](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/blob/master/model_utils/models.py#L126). You don't even need to set it up.